# A closed subset $S$ of $X=R^n$ has a point of minimum distance from any $x \in X$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following:

From the definition of $\inf$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, with $d = \inf_s d(x, s)$, there is $y \in S$ such that:

$d \le d(x,y) < d + \epsilon.$

The we can find $(y_n) \subset S$ such that $lim_n d(x, y_n)=d.$

Because $S$ is closed, $d$ is finite so $(y_n)$ is bounded and so has a convergent subsequence $y_{n_k} \to y^* \in S.$

I need to show $d(x,y^*)=d$, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the extreme value theorem. Since $X$ is closed and $B=\{y:d(x,y)\leq d+1\}$ is compact, $X\cap B$ is also compact. Define the function $f:X\cap B\to\mathbb R$ by $f(y)=d(x,y)$. Since the metric is continuous, $f$ is also continuous. By the extreme value theorem, this function reaches a minimum. You know that for all $\epsilon$, there exists a point $y_\epsilon$ so that $d(x,y_\epsilon)=f(y_\epsilon)<d+\epsilon$. Since $f$ reaches a minimum, then, there must be a point $y^*$ such that $f(y^*)\leq d$. You also know that $f(y)\geq d$ for all $y$. Therefore, $f(y^*)=d.$